# How to use an image for a blog post thumbnail, but NOT have it be the featured image on the top of the post?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have an image that I would like to be used for thumbnails for the page, but I don't want that as a featured image when users come to the page. Does anyone know how to do this in wordpress?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to add a new field for an image in posts (or you can create your own meta field just for the image). Then You can edit your theme to show whatever image, wherever you want.

[ACF Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

---

If you just want to hide the featured image in every post, and only show it in blog page (or a page like that), you need to edit the post template.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using an extension called 'Conditionally display featured image on singular posts and pages'. This allowed me to toggle off the the big picture on the post.

[image]